# Systemd Stopped target Main User Target

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I have multiple services running as `systemd` user services stored under `.config/systemd/user`

They all have the entry `WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Last night all of them stopped, `journalctl` has the following entry

`systemd[1492]: Stopped target Main User Target.`

What happened and why did it happen?

Best

Comment: Automatic updates trying a reboot, but fail?

Answer (score 2):

The services where automatically terminated, after the user logged out.

loginctl enable-linger username

Fixed this